# Age of individuals, given median and average

Tags: algebra-precalculus, statistics, systems-of-equations, word-problem

Average age among three people is 6 where everyone is of different ages. Median age is 8. How old are the people?

I see that

$\frac{x_1+x_2+x_3}{3}=6 \Longleftrightarrow x_1+x_2+x_3 = 18$ and that $x_2 = 8$ so that I get a system of equations

$\begin{equation}\begin{cases}x_1+x_2+x_3 = 18\\x_2=8 \end{cases}\end{equation}$

But now I have three unknowns and two equations, I which doesn't seem solvable. I seem to be missing an equation, right?. A relationship I am not seeing.

Comment: For three distinct data points, the median is the middle point.  Thus, with ages $a<b<c$ we must have $b=8$.  Therefore...

Comment: One of them has to be age 8 as we have an odd sample size and thus the median must fall directly on one of them so someone has to be 8.

Comment: Where did you get the fact that x2= 6?

Comment: Should say:  the answer is still not unique without some assumption (like that everyone's age is a positive integer).

Comment: You also have two inequalities in your system, since $x_2$ is the median, you know $x_1 \le x_2$ and $x_2 \le x_3$.

Comment: @igameonamac I mistyped, it should be x_2=8.

Comment: @AmaanM I believe you mean strict inequalities $(<,>)$ since the problem stated all three people are of different ages. I see that $x_1 < 8$ and $x_3>8$ and putting this into the system of equations gives me a system containing both inequalities and equal signs. I'm not sure I know how to solve these mixed systems.

Comment: @lulu Do you mean therefore $x_1<8<x_3$? I see this but I don't know how it helps. We can probably make the positive integer assumption.

Comment: Yes, $x_1<8<x_3$.  A quick computation then shows that $x_1+x_3=10$.  Given they are both non-negative integers, that forces $(x_1,x_3)$ to be one of $(0,10)$ or $(1,9)$.  If you also assume both are positive integers, that only leaves $(1,9)$.

Comment: @lulu, I actually saw that $x_1+x_3=10$ from one of the equations. Is there a way of calculating the answer? I'm having trouble just seeing that $x_1$ and $x_2$ are forced to be one of (0, 10) or (1,9).

Comment: Just go case by case. You know $x_3>8$ and clearly we must have $x_3\leq 10$ so there are only two possible values for it.

Comment: @saner yes, I missed that, those inequalities should be strict. Note that Lulu's pointing out that if you make the additional assumption that all ages are positive integers, then you further have inequality $x_1 > 0$ (and $x_3 > 0$, but that's redundant to our earlier inequality $x_3 > 8$). Combine that with $x_1 + x_3 = 10$, and you are left with $x_3 = 9$, because if $x_3 \ge 10$ then $x_1 \le 0$, and we wouldn't have a positive integer value for $x_1$.

Answer (score 1):

Without loss of generality, assume that $x_1<x_2<x_3$ (we use strictly less than here because they are different ages). Next, because $x_2=8$, $$x_1+8+x_3=18$$ $$x_1=10-x_3$$ $$x_1<10-8$$
Since somebody cant be 0 years old, we have that $0<x_1<2$, so that $x_1=1$ and $x_3=9$, so the ages are 1, 8, and 9